# Kea DHCP postgresql, the hosts aren't added in the database

Tags: postgresql, dhcp

I configure the Kea DHCP with a postgresql database.
When a lease is created, it is well added in the database but when a new host is connected, nothing is created in the database in the table "hosts"

```
    "lease-database": {
        "type": "postgresql",
        "name": "dhcp",
        "user": "kea",
        "password": "toto",
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 5432
     },

    "hosts-database": {
        "type": "postgresql",
        "name": "dhcp",
        "user": "kea",
        "password": "toto",
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 5432
    },
```

Actually I have well my leases:

```
address  |     hwaddr     | client_id | valid_lifetime |         expire         | subnet_id | fqdn_fwd | fqdn_rev | hostname | state | user_context
-----------+----------------+-----------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+--------------
 172491571 | \x506b8d5a2d9a | \x        |           4000 | 2018-12-26 11:41:27+00 |         1 | t        | t        | debian   |     0 |
 172491573 | \x506b8d708a62 | \x        |           4000 | 2018-12-26 12:07:31+00 |         1 | t        | t        | debian   |     0 |
 172491572 | \x506b8d2abde6 | \x        |           4000 | 2018-12-26 12:09:49+00 |         1 | t        | t        | debian   |     0 |

(3 rows)
```

But I don't have any hosts in my database.

```
 host_id | dhcp_identifier | dhcp_identifier_type | dhcp4_subnet_id | dhcp6_subnet_id | ipv4_address | hostname | dhcp4_client_classes | dhcp6_client_classes | dhcp4_next_server | dhcp4_server_hostname | dhcp4_boot_file_name | user_context | auth_key
---------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------------+----------
(0 rows)
```

I miss an element in the config to enable the addition of a host in DB ?

Answer (score 1):

The respond from https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/kea/issues/370:
"You misunderstood. The hosts database is host reservations. This is a table sysadmin may enter reservations into, such as "device with MAC address X on subnet Y should get address Z and option W". If you don't insert any, the hosts will get addresses from a regular dynamic pool. This should be the case. The address that's being assigned ("leased") is recorded in lease-database, see lease4 or lease6 tables.
You can insert the host reservations manually using SQL commands or use host commands hook. That hook extends Kea with an easy to use REST API interface that allows you to add reservations. Kea will sanity check your data and, if correct, will insert them into the database (as you did for hosts-database) you have configured."

If it can help someone